# How to find number of chars in a list of chars?

Tags: java

I have a list of chars:

```
private char alphabet[] = {
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M',
    'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z',
    'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm',
    'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z',
    '`', '~', '!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '-',
    '_', '=', '+', '[', '{', ']', '}', '\\', '|', ':', ';', '\'', '"',
    ',', '<', '.', '>', '/', '?', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7',
    '8', '9', '0'
};
```

How can I find how many chars are in that list?

Comment: I haven't tried anything because I don't know what to try

Comment: Do you need to check if there are duplicates or can you be certain that there aren't any?

Comment: I searched for duplicates and couldn't find any

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not a *list*, that's an array of type `char`.  To find the length of arrays, you can use `alphabet.length`.

Comment: I tried this 
    private int numberOfChars = alphabet.length;
but it doesn't work

Comment: @KaidenPlozza what do you expect?

Comment: Depends on where you used it.  If you used it *before* you declared the array, that's a problem.

Comment: explain "doesn't work"?

Comment: You did declare it as `private`. Where are you trying to use it? Check out Oracle's [Java array tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

Comment: @Alias:  That shouldn't matter so long as it's being used in the scope of the object itself (that is, not in `main`).  Given the usage example, I'm willing to bet that it's being used as another field (why I do not know).

Comment: I just needed to put it after the chars

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `alphabet.length`? You can find the length of any array using `.length`

Answer (score 0):

**alphabet.length** works.

```
 System.out.println(alphabet.length);//printed 94
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps. Use .length for an array as follows

```
public class CharredFlesh{

private char [] alphabet = {
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M',
    'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z',
    'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm',
    'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z',
    '`', '~', '!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '-',
    '_', '=', '+', '[', '{', ']', '}', '\\', '|', ':', ';', '\'', '"',
    ',', '<', '.', '>', '/', '?', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7',
    '8', '9', '0'
};

public char[] getChars(){
return this.alphabet;
}

public static void main(String[]args){

CharredFlesh terminator = new CharredFlesh();   
int length = terminator.length; 
System.out.println("You have " + length + " characters");

}//main

}
```